# SQL Server 2008, display only one value from col1 which has multiple values associated in col2 of same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table

```
**Col1      Col2**
A            1          
A            2
A            3
A            4
B            1
B            2
B            3
B            4
c            1
c            2
```

Now with this, I need to find Values from col1 which is related to four values of col2. e.g.if 'A' is related to the four values in col2 'A' should be displayed and same with 'B' but not 'c', don't have to display values from col2 but if you can that's a plus. And I don't have any query for this.please help

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way, provided that you want to get the values from `col1` that there's a corresponding value in `col2` for all values of `col2`:

```
select col1
from coltable
group by col1
having count(distinct col2) = (select count(distinct col2) from coltable)
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a3b58/1)

Comment: If you don't mind, can you tell me if my query is okay too. Any disadvantages of my query ? It works though.

Comment: I deleted my answer since you mentioned that it uses hardcoding. For the record, my query was `Select *
from
(
select col1, count(col2) as cnt
from coltable
group by col1
) as src
where src.col1 not in ('c')`

Answer (score 0):

```
;with CTE AS
(
select distinct col1,COUNT(col2)as Col2,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY COL1) AS RN  from @coltable
GROUP BY col1
)
select COL1,Col2 from CTE WHERE RN <> 3
```